# How to parse RetroFit 2 response by specific key

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse the ResponseBody json object. I then need to create a WarehouseList array of Warehouse objects. Here is my response json.

```
{
    "GetUserWarehouseListResult": [
        {
            "Message": null,
            "WarehouseId": 31232,
            "WarehouseName": "ABQ"
        },
        {
            "Message": null,
            "WarehouseId": 22113,
            "WarehouseName": "AMS"
        },
        {
            "Message": null,
            "WarehouseId": 21645,
            "WarehouseName": "ORD"
        }
}
```

In objective-c, I can do this with below:

```
for (NSDictionary* element in [dictionary objectforKey:@"GetUserWarehouseListResult"]) {
}
```

However, I need help doing this in Kotlin with RetroFit2

Here is my current code:

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            val stringResponse = response.body()?.string()
            Log.d(TAG,"Response: " + stringResponse)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own model class based on your response, instead of passing `ResponseBody`

Like this;

```
public class RestResponse {

    private ArrayList<GetUserWarehouseListResult> GetUserWarehouseListResult;

    public ArrayList<GetUserWarehouseListResult> getGetUserWarehouseListResult ()    {
        return GetUserWarehouseListResult;
    }

    public void setGetUserWarehouseListResult (ArrayList<GetUserWarehouseListResult> GetUserWarehouseListResult)    {
        this.GetUserWarehouseListResult = GetUserWarehouseListResult;
    }

  
    
    public class GetUserWarehouseListResult {
    
        private String Message;
        private String WarehouseId;
        private String WarehouseName;

        public String getMessage ()    {
            return Message;
        }

        public void setMessage (String Message)    {
            this.Message = Message;
        }

        public String getWarehouseId ()    {
            return WarehouseId;
        }

        public void setWarehouseId (String WarehouseId)    {
            this.WarehouseId = WarehouseId;
        }

        public String getWarehouseName ()    {
            return WarehouseName;
        }

        public void setWarehouseName (String WarehouseName)    {
            this.WarehouseName = WarehouseName;
        }

    }
}
```

Now Pass this class in your retrofitCall; use 'RestResponse' instead of 'ResponseBody'

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<RestResponse>, response: Response<RestResponse>) {
            val responseObj: RestResponse? = response.body()
            Log.d(TAG,"Response: " + responseObj!!.getGetUserWarehouseListResult())
        }
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Converters` API in `Retrofit` to integrate a third-party JSON parser library (like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)) with `Retrofit` so that it can parse JSON responses to data classes automatically.

You can read [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) about how to use `Converters` and implement them in `Retrofit`.

Comment: I am using GSON, but still having trouble figuring out how to specify the key of the result